# Comparison of Crossroads.js and router.js

Tags: javascript, browser, url-routing, crossroadsjs, routerjs

Looks like crossroads.js is much older than router.js. All the articles about crossroads.js seem to be from 2011. I'm wondering if anyone has a comparison:

- reasons why you'd use one over the other
- differences in how they operate
- etc

See also: https://github.com/tildeio/router.js/issues/108

Answer (score 2):

A reasonably good answer to my question was posted here: https://github.com/tildeio/router.js/issues/108